# Retrieving data from my API in Expo simulator takes 2 seconds to load, but in production app it takes 7 seconds, every time

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, expo

Not sure how to fix this, my API is running on beanstalk. Not sure if it's a server side or client side issue. When I run npm expo start then I to open iOS simulator, retrieving data from the API and hydrating takes only 2 seconds on every page. When I deploy the app to the app store, and even on testflight, my iPhone takes 7 seconds every time to load data. Any help would be appreciated! There are no logs for an API response time or front end hydration taking longer than expected, though I could use general logs throughout my code to track which side is being slow.

Just to be clear, I am using the same WiFi on both devices, yet the simulator on computer is faster. I am not using a VPN on either, and I've tested using cellular instead on device (I use Verizon so it's even faster than my WiFi, but still 7 second load time).

It's possible this is an expo issue, but asking the community in case anyone's encountered this and knows a solution!